# Parallels with Windows 11 VM - map a network drive to a folder on a different Mac connected over Ethernet

Tags: network, windows, parallels-desktop, apple-silicon

I have Parallels 18 with a Windows 11 VM with the host on Apple Silicon. The VM runs normally. I am able to map network locations to drive letter for locations on the host machine.

What I would like to do is map a drive in the Windows VM to a folder on a different Mac computer that is connected via Ethernet (and also via wifi and Bluetooth). When I try to map a drive, I only see in the "Network" the local to the host machine locations.

It would seem that I should be able to map to other networked machines.

I have tried the following configuration changes, but nothing has worked so far.

- Change VM Configure > Hardware > Network > Source to Ethernet;
- changed Devices > Network from Shared to Bridged > Ethernet;
- enabled nearby sharing in Windows;

It is possible to map a network drive in the Windows VM to another local machine?

EDIT 1

I think I have resolved this. I tried a lot of things, but I think the thing that worked was that I had to go into Parallels > Configure > Sharing > Share Mac > Manage Folders. There I had to add a checkmark next to the host Mac machine name. The check mark for the user name then dimmed as it is included in the whole machine.

After that I was able to see the drives attached to the host.

I am thinking it might be best to undo some of the other steps I tried. But a bit hesitant for fear of losing something.

Comment: If you configured the Windows VM to use a bridged network adapter, then it’s on the same LAN as the host running it and any other computers on the network.  Simply share the folder in Windows and connect to the Windows VM using SMB. You may have to use the IP address if your network (router) doesn’t support dnsmasq.

Comment: @Allan you said "share the folder in Windows". The host is macOS, so I don't know if your instruction applies.

Comment: Treat the Windows VM as it’s own computer on the network because, it is.  Since it’s bridged, virtualization no longer applies here.